# Non-standard REST API in Backbone js

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I am building Backbone.js models backed by a legacy REST API.  When I create a new resource on the server, rather than return the JSON of the newly created resource, it returns plain text of the id of the newly created resource, along with a relative URL in the Location header where the resource can be gotten.

For example, I POST:

```
{ "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Blow" }
```

to `http://fakeserver.com/people` and (on success) the body of the plain/text response might be: "1234".  The status of the response is 201 and the Location header would be `http://fakeserver.com/people/1234`.  If I GET from that Location URL, it will have

```
{ "id": 1234, "firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Blow" }
```

How would I override the sync function on my model to accommodate this convention instead of the default Backbone.js conventions?

To clarify, there is no Backbone.js version of this yet - I am trying to create a new one.  The old jQuery-only way of doing it was:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: submitURL,
   data: $.toJSON(person),
   success: function(data, status, request) {
     showSuccessMessage();
     closeDialog();
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json'
 });
```

The details of the showSuccessMessage and closeDialog are unimportant - just to demonstrate that basically we are just ignoring the content of the response and throwing the original object away.

Comment: Please include the Backbone.js code you use to `POST` to this server.

Comment: There is no Backbone.js version of this code yet, but POSTing to the server will work without overriding standard sync function. It's just handling the response that's different.

Comment: Then please include the code you use to handle the response.

Comment: OK, I've updated the question to hopefully clarify.  The old code to handle the response basically ignored the response (except that it was a success).

Answer (score 0):

Handle the simple text response with parse:
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

```
parse : function(response, options){
   console.log(response, options);
   var data = this.toJSON(): //current model to hash
   data.id = response; <- assuming that response is a simple text plain id
   return data;
}
```

You could also use sync to overwrite something in the ajax call(that is not supported in the options hash.
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync

Comment: I thought about using parse, but that would also affect fetch, right?

Comment: yes, you can use options to know what request is and only modify if it is a save. Check in the Chrome console the value for options.